# 4 Pdfs into 2x2 PDF single page not working

Tags: python, pdf, pypdf

I am trying to code a converter to give an amount of pdf pages via input directory so that they get merged on a single pdf page. Sort of what you can do when printing a pdf book you can select how many pages you want to be printed on a single page. So i want to be able to specify the grid pattern (2x2, 2x3 and so on). However my code is returning a document that just merges these 4 pages together. Can someone help me find my error?

```
import os
from PyPDF2 import PdfReader, PdfWriter

def create_grid_pdf(input_folder, output_file, rows, columns):
    pdf_writer = PdfWriter()

    # Get all PDF files from the input folder
    pdf_files = [file for file in os.listdir(input_folder) if file.endswith('.pdf')]

    # Sort PDF files to ensure the same order each time
    pdf_files.sort()

    for pdf_file in pdf_files:
        pdf_path = os.path.join(input_folder, pdf_file)
        pdf_reader = PdfReader(pdf_path)

        for page_num in range(len(pdf_reader.pages)):
            page = pdf_reader.pages[page_num]
            page.scale_by(scale)
            pdf_writer.add_page(page)

    # Calculate the number of pages to print per grid page
    pages_per_grid_page = rows * columns

    # Create grid pattern by merging pages
    for start_page in range(0, len(pdf_writer.pages), pages_per_grid_page):
        end_page = start_page + pages_per_grid_page
        grid_page = PdfWriter()

        for page in pdf_writer.pages[start_page:end_page]:
            grid_page.add_page(page)

        with open(output_file, 'ab') as output_pdf:
            grid_page.write(output_pdf)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    input_folder = "C:\Users\InputPdf"
    output_file = "C:\Users\output.pdf"
    rows = 2
    columns = 2

    create_grid_pdf(input_folder, output_file, rows, columns)
```

Comment: You need to resize the pages (by 50%) and transform them to place them in the four corners of the page.  It's not doing that automatically.

Comment: i used the scale_by(0.5) methode but it just scales down all 4 pages and merges them to a 4 page document. Any ideas on whats going wrong?

Comment: That's exactly what you're asking it to do. You're using add_page four times, so you get four pages. You need to look at the PyPDF2 documentation for how to stamp one page on top of another e.g https://pypdf2.readthedocs.io/en/3.0.0/user/add-watermark.html

Comment: Right.  You seem to be thinking that PyPDF2 is automatically going to combine the pages somehow, but that's not the case.  YOU have to reduce the pages, and YOU have to paste four pages together on one new page.